# 37 - No locks available' from fcntl while using Multi Instance MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to set up Multi Instacnce MQ. I am using `MQ v7.5`. I am following the below steps:

1. Installed MQ in Server A and Server B
2. Configured NFS in Server A(acting as server) and in Server B (acting as client) in a folder `MQ`.
3. Created a queue manager in server A using the below command `crtmqm -ld /MQ/logs -md /MQ/qmrgs -q QM1`
4. Got the queue manager information using `dspmqinf -o command QM1`
5. In Server B used `addmqinf <queue info from server A>`
6. Start the queue manager in Server A using `strmqm -x QM1` and its started successfully.
7. Start the queue manager in Server B using `strmqm -x QM1` and its failed to start.

I got the below FDC:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
| WebSphere MQ First Failure Symptom Report                                   | 
| =========================================                                   | 
|                                                                             |
| Date/Time         :- Mon November 10 2014 15:23:29 IST                      | 
| UTC Time          :- 1415613209.614999                                      | 
| UTC Time Offset   :- 330 (IST)                                              | 
| Host Name         :- InBlrBnc60                                             | 
| Operating System  :- Linux 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64                             | 
| PIDS              :- 5724H7230                                              | 
| LVLS              :- 7.5.0.0                                                | 
| Product Long Name :- WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)               | 
| Vendor            :- IBM                                                    | 
| Installation Path :- /opt/mqm                                               | 
| Installation Name :- Installation1    (1)                                   | 
| Probe Id          :- XY509007                                               | 
| Application Name  :- MQM                                                    | 
| Component         :- xcsOpenFileLock                                        | 
| SCCS Info         :- /build/p000_P/src/lib/cs/unix/amqxnflx.c,              | 
| Line Number       :- 428                                                    | 
| Build Date        :- Jun  4 2012                                            | 
| Build Level       :- p000-L120604                                           | 
| Build Type        :- IKAP - (Production)                                    | 
| Effective UserID  :- 525 (mqm)                                              | 
| Real UserID       :- 525 (mqm)                                              | 
| Program Name      :- crtmqm                                                 | 
| Addressing mode   :- 64-bit                                                 | 
| LANG              :- en_US.UTF-8                                            | 
| Process           :- 16729                                                  | 
| Process(Thread)   :- 16729                                                  | 
| Thread            :- 1                                                      | 
| ThreadingModel    :- PosixThreads                                           | 
| QueueManager      :- MQ1                                                    | 
| UserApp           :- FALSE                                                  | 
| ConnId(2) QM      :- 2                                                      | 
| Last HQC          :- 2.0.0-5133648                                          | 
| Last HSHMEMB      :- 2.1.1-22456                                            | 
| Major Errorcode   :- xecF_E_UNEXPECTED_SYSTEM_RC                            | 
| Minor Errorcode   :- OK                                                     | 
| Probe Type        :- MSGAMQ6119                                             | 
| Probe Severity    :- 2                                                      | 
| Probe Description :- AMQ6119: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred   |
|   ('37 - No locks available' from fcntl.)                                   | 
| FDCSequenceNumber :- 0                                                      | 
| Arith1            :- 37 (0x25)                                              | 
| **Comment1          :- '37 - No locks available' from fcntl.**
```

I tried browsing about 37 - No locks available' from fcntl, but not able to get why this error is coming. I have verified my system config with `su mqm -c /opt/mqm/bin/mqconfig` and it satisfies the MQ recommended value. I have also verified my NFS set up is working fine.

Comment: Just curios: Have you given the correct queue manager name? FDC says queue manager name as MQ1 whereas you mention the command issued as "strmqm -x QM1"? Hope it's a typo when posting this query.

Comment: @Shashi Thanks for the response. Apologizing for the typo, its QM1 only in the actual FDC file.

Comment: This may not be a MQ problem. I like to point you to this RHEL link: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43001

Comment: Thanks for the link. The link points to the issue, i did not find any solution about how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you subscribed to RedHad? I think only registered users can read the solution. The site says "This solution has been verified to work by Red Hat Customers and Support Engineers for the specified product version(s).

This solution is part of Red Hat's fast-track publication program, providing a huge library of solutions that Red Hat engineers have created while supporting our customers. To give you the knowledge you need the instant it becomes available, these articles may be presented in a raw and unedited form." So I believe there is some solution available.

Comment: I have not subscribed to RedHat, however I have registered myself in RedHat website. But still not able to view any solution once login there.